# AngleSharp Использование QuerySelectorAll

Tags: c#, html, .net, веб-программирование, парсер

Элемент со следующим XPath: `/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]`; содержит в себе множество дочерних элементов `div`, в каждом из которых по относительному пути располагается элемент `div/div[2]/div[2]/a`, который содержит интересующую меня информацию. Каким образом мне получить все такие элементы с использованием библиотеки AngleSharp? То есть "XPath" получается в таком духе: `/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[*]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a`, где * - число от 2 до N.

Отдельно хочу спросить как поступить в ситуации, когда путь до элемента немного меняется. Возможно есть более надёжный способ, нежели XPath.

Comment: Не описываете код словами! Это я не знаю, как сходить к мастерам и сказать им "хочу ремонт в двухкомнатной квартире". И вот будут они сидеть, гадать что надо, какой дизайн, какие материалы, какие размеры и куча всего еще. Также и тут, вы сказали элемент в элементе, ок, но может там есть классы, id или другие данные, по которым в разы можно сократить получение данных. И да, строить xPath на одних индексах, очень, очень плохо!

Comment: Можно сперва получить коллекцию дивов (где звёздочка), а потом у дивов с нужными индексами вторым XPath-запросом получать элемент a.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Логичное решение. Ну а как с использованием AngleSharp реализовать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ _"может там есть классы, id или другие данные, по которым в разы можно сократить получение данных"_ - Есть, но они постоянно меняются. _"И да, строить xPath на одних индексах, очень, очень плохо!"_ - Что ещё можно задействовать кроме индексов? _"И вот будут они сидеть, гадать что надо, какой дизайн, какие материалы, какие размеры и куча всего еще"_ - Какой информацией как вы считаете нужно дополнить вопрос?

Comment: @D.Stark Я вам уже сказал какой. Говорите про код - давайте код (HTML). `кроме индексов` - Вроде тоже сказал - id и классы. Вы не должны быть завязаны на кол-ве объектов, как и на структуре HTML. Вот есть у вас к примеру объект гдет в середине страницы с классом `test`, ну вот вы и пишете `//*[@class='test']`, все. Заметьте, не пишу весь путь (включая `/html/body`). `они постоянно меняются` - ну так найдите то, что не меняется) Например, часто бывает `<div id="id-123456">`, как видите, `id-` неизменно, можно искать по нему. Короче, без HTML дать вам ответ, ну, невозможно...

Answer (score 2):

Возьмём пример из документации и распарсим одну из страниц Википедии.

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
var address = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Big_Bang_Theory_episodes";
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = await context.OpenAsync(address);
        
var tableSelector = "table";
var tdSelector = "td.summary";

var tables = document.QuerySelectorAll(tableSelector);
                    
for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
{
    var title = tables[i].QuerySelector(tdSelector);
    Console.WriteLine(title.TextContent);
}
```

`tableSelector` - это ваш `/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div`. У вас это будет `divSelector`.

`tdSelector` - это ваш `/div/div[2]/div[2]/a`. У вас это будет `linkSelector`.

Получаем первым запросом часть данных в коллекцию. И проходим циклом по нужным индексам от 2 до N. Получаем вторым запросом конкретные данные. У меня это название первой серии в каждом сезоне. У вас это будет элемент `a`.

Comment: Почему бы не выбрать сразу `"table td.summary"`?

Comment: @aepot - у автора в середине xpath опорные div'ы, от которых отсчитывается дальнейший маршрут. Я просто пытался повторить такое поведение, хотя для страницы Вики это не нужно.